# LLVM: Do I have to set a target layout or is it better to set a target triple?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am learning the basics of the LLVM framework. I read about the target layout that describes the datatypes and about the target triple that describes the machine and the OS.
However I was not able to find information about what is really mandatory to be set and why.
I found examples where none of these is set or where one or the other is set. Obviously, it is not necessary to set either for a working IR file, yet I am under the impression that the developers want me to set something there, why else would this interface be exposed?

My understanding is, that based on the target triple, LLVM should be able to derive the correct datalayout by itself, but if that is so, why is it possible to set the data layout by hand.

So what is the correct way of doing this? Which way should I chose? Set the target triple or define the complete layout by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataLayout is going to become mandatory so I'd highly suggest you use that. The reason for being able to put a DataLayout in without a Triple is so that you could have target independent transforms that need DataLayout to work. The triple will affect code generation when you get to that point.

In the future we hope to have an API that front end writers can use/modify that will enable them to get a default triple from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The LLVM folks recommend setting both a target triple and a data layout specification.

> Make sure that your Modules contain both a data layout specification and target triple. Without these pieces, non of the target specific optimization will be enabled. This can have a major effect on the generated code quality.

From http://llvm.org/docs/Frontend/PerformanceTips.html#the-basics

There's a [LLVMGetDefaultTargetTriple](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/c_2TargetMachine_8h.html#a873fa19524cffa775e6d8d45ffe95dad) function which can get the target specification of your local machine.

Comment: Is there also a function for getting the data layout of the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> My understanding is, that based on the target triple, LLVM should be
>   able to derive the correct datalayout by itself, but if that is so,
>   why is it possible to set the data layout by hand.

I thought this, too. But actually, the optimizer wants the data layout set explicitly. Otherwise it assumes a default layout which can corrupt your code. See for example:
https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45188